# Redirect IP address and subfolder to a new domain name

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Some of my pages are being indexed with the IP address and a subfolder/user folder.  What is the best way to force all of the traffic to example root folder address:

```
123.456.789.012/~user/path1/path2/
```

to redirect to

```
domainname.com/path1/path2/
```

to be more clear about it... *123.456.789.012/~user* is my root domain.  I need all of that traffic to go to *domainname.com*.  I cannot have the new address appear as *domainname.com/~user/* because that folder is not part of the domain name's address.

*123.456.789.012/~user* ---should exactly redirect to--> *domainname.com*

Comment: this would generally only happen if you had links with the ip on the site, so that should be fixed.

Comment: Someone hard coded the links with IP address, but now Google has them and is still sending traffic to them.  So I want to redirect all of that traffic to the new address and not lose the visitor.

Comment: you can ask google to remove links. http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1663416

Comment: really? you can remove listings from google's index ? that's neat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an `.htaccess` file to force the use of your domain:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domainname.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domainname.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

EDIT:
Or, to also remove the `~user` part:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:~user\/)?(.*)$ http://domainname.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: So my real question is, does that address the fact that I cant have the "/~user/" show up after domainname.com/?

Comment: @MikeWish My edit should address that.

Comment: So the last line you added to remove the /~user/, does that get used instead of the last line you had in the first block of code?

Comment: @MikeWise Yes, instead. Give it a shot. Incidentally, my code rewrites even if `~user/` doesn't exist in the url, but will remove it if it does exist.

Comment: This worked.  Thank you so much!  I subbed in the bottom line and that did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: So my real question is, does that address the fact that I cant have the "/~user/" show up after domainname.com/?

Comment: Did you test this answer on your web server? And clarify whether you want `"/~user/"` to show up or not after domainname.com?

Comment: To clarify.  The site has an address at 123.456.789.012/~user/.  That is the root of the site.  I want that address to redirect to domain.com.  /~user/ needs to be removed in that redirect and all other redirects like 123.456.789.012/~user/file.pdf.  In that case 123.456.789.012/~user/file.pdf needs to redirect to domain.com/file.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

try this, will redirect to */path1/path2* instead */~user/path1/path2*

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^~user/(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```